# Higienização de variável X filtro de variáveis antes da inserção no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Peguei um projeto para realizar alguns ajustes e notei que havia algumas brechas de segurança nas entradas de dados do banco, não pude fazer alterações nas querys mas pude realizar adaptações, fiz as implementações abaixo mas não sei ao certo se deixei passar algo relevante sobre a prevenção de sql injection, alguma sugestão de melhoria?

Tenho uma função para limpar as variáveis:

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('limpa_sql_injection') ) {
    function limpa_sql_injection($string) {
        $string = str_replace("UNION SELECT"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("UNION INSERT"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("UNION DELETE"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("UNION UPDATE"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("uid="," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("uid ="," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("pwd="," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("pwd ="," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("admin=","",$string);
        $string = str_replace("admin =","",$string);
        $string = str_replace("exec master"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("cdmshell"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("net user"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("or uid"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("username=","",$string);
        $string = str_replace("username =","",$string);
        $string = str_replace("ALTER TABLE"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("alter table"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("--"," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("OR 1="," ",$string);
        $string = str_replace("or 1=1","",$string);
        $string = str_replace("OR 1=1","",$string);
        $string = str_replace("or 1=","",$string);
        $string = str_ireplace('%3Cscript', '',$string);
        return $string;

    }
}
?>
```

Tratar a entrada das variáveis:

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('filtra_var') ){
    function filtra_var($var) {
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        //$var = htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        //$var = fgetss($var);
        $var = addslashes($var);
        $var = filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $var = limpa_sql_injection($var);
        return $var;
    }
}
?>
```

E fazendo uso da mesma antes de passar para a Query:

```
<?php
$var = filtra_var($_POST['var']);
?>
```

Depois passo para a Query:

```
<?php
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `tabela` (`var`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$var)."');
?>
```

É seguro desse modo ou ainda corro o risco de injeções SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a forma de deixar menos volumoso seu código seja criando um `array()` com os valores referentes às alterações que você quer fazer com o `str_replace()`, sendo assim, sempre que quiser adicionar algum outro valor, basta adicionar nesse `array()`:

```
function limpa_sql_injection($string){
    $to_replace=array("UNION SELECT","UNION INSERT","UNION DELETE","UNION UPDATE","uid","uid","pwd","pwd","admin","admin","exec master","cdmshell","net user","or uid","username","username ","ALTER TABLE","alter table","--","OR 1=","or 1=1","OR 1=1","or 1=","%3Cscript");
    foreach ($to_replace as $key => $value) {
        $string=str_replace($value,"",$string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Outra coisa importante é tratar os dados usando, por exemplo, expressões regulares. O nome do usuário deve ser um nick alfanumérico?

```
$string=preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]]/","",$string);
```

Assim obriga a string a conter apenas caracteres alfanuméricos, etc.

Aconselho o uso do `bindValue()` porque acaba sendo mais eficaz, ainda mais quando usado o tratamento adequado para cada tipo de entrada.

Comment: não pude fazer isso, até porque precisava de tempo e não tinha para alterar todas as querys, eram mais de 80 querys para um ajuste, dei a sugestão de criar as funções, foram aceitas e pude inserir nas variáveis. Obrigado pelas dicas, vou fazer uso da array que tá mais eficaz. Gratidão!